# Viewing another session's settings

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

It is [possible in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/how-can-i-view-what-nls-settings-are-active-for-other-session/125651#125651) to examine the session-level settings for sessions other than your own (subject to privs obv). Is there an equivalent method in Postgres 9 or 10?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. PostreSQL session variables are meant for 
mostly scripts to run in the same session. If you need persisting variables across user, or a place to store state -- PostgreSQL can do that too, just use a table.

From there you can limit access to the table through Pg access permissions or getter-setter functions.

Here is an example of such a scheme, https://www.depesz.com/2009/08/20/getting-session-variables-without-touching-postgresql-conf/

Comment: It's not about sharing variables so much as it is diagnosing an unexpected behaviour without interrupting a running process, that what we used this feature for in my Oracle days anyway